# SQLite: How to extract primary keys and unique constraints with correct names

Tags: sqlite

Given a SQLite db.

a table with primary key:

```
create table t1 (id int not null, CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Now query info for it:

```
PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(t1);
```

returns:

`| cid | name | type | notnull | dflt_value | pk | 
| --- | ---- | ---- | ------- | -----------| -- | 
| 0   | id   | int  | 1       | <null>     | 1  |`

```
PRAGMA index_list(t1);
```

returns:

`| seq | name                  | unique | origin | partial |
| --- | ----------------------| ------ | ------ | ------- |
| 0   | sqlite_autoindex_t1_1 | 1      | pk     | 0       |`

As we can see `index_list` returns info about the PK but it reports incorrect name ("sqlite_autoindex_t1_1" instead of "pk_t1").

The same problem with UNIQUE constraints. They are created with autogenerated names.

Is it possible to extract real PRIMARY KEY/UNIQUE CONSTRAINT name?

P.S. I can see that JetBrains's DataGrip correctly show PK names in database browser. But sqliteadmin for example shows them with name like sqlite_autoindex_t1_1. For unique constraints even DataGrip doesn't show correct names (actually it doesn't show them at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index and the constraint are different objects.

SQLite has no mechanism to retrieve the constraint name. You'd have to parse the SQL.